# How to use increment method for strong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What I'd like to do is to increment the value in the association model when I update.

`schedule` has_many `rooms` and `rooms` belongs_to `schedule`.
I'd like to increment `day` in the room model.

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true` is also defined in the `schedule.rb`

Although fields except `day` will be inputted via view, I'd like to update only `day` automatically.

I tried to use `increment` method and so on, but I haven't figured out how to apply.

The view image as I expect is as followings;

```
Day1
schedule_title1 (Mar 25, 2016)
    room_name1
```

After added new day;

```
Day1
schedule_title1 (Mar 25, 2016)
    room_name1
Day2
schedule_title2 (Mar 26, 2016)
    room_name2
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
    t.integer  "day",   default: 1   #I'd like to increment when I update
    ...
  end
```

**schedlues_controller.rb**

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
...
  def update

    #I tried some code here before update

    if @schedule.update(schedule_params)
      flash[:success] = "schedule updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end 
...
  private

    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :departure_date,  rooms_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :room, :day])
    end
```

When I press "Add room" button and update after entering some, I'd like to increment `day`.

**_schedule_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :departure_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control' %>

  <div id="room">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |r| %>
      <%= r.input :room %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add room", :rooms, data: {target: '#room'}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: how about attaching a callback to update on room itself? I'm not fully sure of the situations you would want to increment day though. `after_update -> { increment!(:day) }`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @oreoluwa. As you commented, it might be unclear what I want. So I made new question [How to get the max value and set to max + 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228240/how-to-get-the-max-value-and-set-to-max-1). It would be appreciated if you could give me any idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Rails counter_cache method [Rails Guide - Counter Cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).  Convention would be to name the `days` column `schedules_count` instead but you can specify the column in the counter_cache declaration.

So in your Schedule model, you need to add counter_cache to your belongs_to association for room.

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :room, counter_cache: :days

end
```

This is better than a callback with `increment` because it handles when you destroy a schedule as well.