# Rails4: How to set max value + 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Give the following models:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
end
```

What I'd like to do is to set the maximum value + 1 to the added data.

For example, before update

```
Day 1
schedule_title A
    room_name A
```

after update,

```
Day 1
schedule_title A
    room_name A

Day 2    # I'd like to set `2` to `day` column in room table
schedule_title B
    room_name B
```

I'd like to set `2` to `day` column for new data in the rooms table when I add next room.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "schedule_id"
    t.integer  "day",   default: 1
    ...
  end

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "departure_date"
    ...
  end
```

When I press "Add room" button and update after entering some, I'd like to set maximum value + 1 to `day` for new data in room table.

**_schedule_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for(@schedule) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  <%= f.label :departure_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :departure_date, class: 'form-control' %>

  <div id="room">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rooms do |r| %>
      <%= r.input :room %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "Add room", :rooms, data: {target: '#room'}, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

**schedlues_controller.rb**

```
class SchedulesController < ApplicationController
...
  def update

    if @schedule.update(schedule_params)
      flash[:success] = "schedule updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end 
...
  private

    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :departure_date,  rooms_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :room, :day])
    end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Room.maximum(:day)
```

Should give you the maximum value in day column of rooms table.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,@dkp. I'd like to know how to set this value + 1 to the new record.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches.

**Approach 1:** Do it Yourself

Try the following:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
  before_create :set_date

  protected
  def set_date
    if self.date.nil?
      self.date = self.schedule.rooms.collect(&:date).max + 1
    end

    true
  end
end
```

**Approach 2:** Use an existing implementation

Take a look at [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list). There `position` is equivalent to your `date`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Dharam. Although I tried `Approach 1`, the day doesn't increment(still 1). In my log `[1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT MAX("rooms"."day") FROM "rooms" WHERE "rooms"."schedule_id" = ?[0m  [["schedule_id", 249]]` was outputted. So I tried SQL `select max(day) from rooms where schedule_id = 249;` the result is `1`.